# How to do pattern matching with date in unix

Tags: grep, logs, date

I would like to extract last 1 hour data from a file.
I have written the below script:

```
Date="$(date -d -1hour +"%b %d, %Y %l:mi:ss %p")" 
grep "$Date" /tmp/user/file.log  > TMP.log
```

The problem is, when I execute it, the data for the time of AM and PM both appears.
Looks like there is some issue with the format of date.
Can someone please help me, so that, only if the current date is in AM only AM data gets added to `TMP.log`.

file. log content:

```
<Dec  4, 2019 10:59:34 AM PST> <Error> <oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.inbound.ImapEmailStore> <SDP-26123> <Could not initialize Email Store for: user , server outlook.office365.com, folder INBOX, sslEnabled true
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
<Dec  4, 2019 10:59:34 PM PST> <Error> <oracle.sdpinternal.messaging.driver.email.inbound.ImapEmailStore> <SDP-26123> <Could not initialize Email Store for: user, server outlook.office365.com, folder INBOX, sslEnabled true
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Comment: What does `echo "$Date"` display? Please add the output to your question in a code block.

Comment: It looks like you're going to be matching the time one hour ago, not all records in the last hour. To do this you're going to need to do something like converting the time an hour ago to seconds, and then (on the fly) convert the time for each log file record to seconds, extracting only those records more recent then your timestamp. I'm not in a position to give you code for this, still not a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

`date -d -1hour +"%b %d, %Y %l:mi:ss %p"` outputs something like:

```
Dec 05, 2019  6:mi:ss am # GB
Dec 05, 2019  6:mi:ss AM # US
Dez 05, 2019  6:mi:ss    # DE
déc. 05, 2019  6:mi:ss   # FR
```

Depending on your locale.

But even the US one is nowhere near the format used in your log file.

Try

```
LC_ALL=C date -d -1hour +"%b %e, %Y %r %Z"
```

(assuming you're in US Pacific timezone (like `America/Los_Angeles`) for which `%Z` would typically expand to `PST`).

That gives something like:

```
Dec  4, 2019 10:17:38 PM PST
```